# Haplologie - exemples dans l'usage réel (quotidien)

Tags: linguistique, phonétique

Quelqu'un vient de poser [une question intéressante sur la linguistique à English Language & Usage.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/456824/72143), ce qui concerne [l'haplologie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplologie) (l'amuïssement d'un ou plusieurs phonèmes répétés ou proches). Wikipédia donne quelques exemples:

- **l'ectricité** pour **l'électricité**
- **Oui, j'irai** pour **Oui, j'y irai**
- **Oui, j'en ai obtenu** pour **Oui, j'en en ai obtenu**

Je n'ai entendu que le deuxième exemple dans l'usage quotidien. Il y a de meilleurs exemples en anglais comme les suivantes:

- **probly** pour **probably** (j'utilise tous les jours !)
- **bana** pour **banana** (très souvent utilisé par les enfants de moins de 3 ans)
- **libry** pour **library** (je ne l'utilise pas trop, mais je l'entend souvent)

**Est-ce qu'il y a de meilleurs exemples d'haplologie dans le français quotidien ?**

---

Someone just posted [an interesting question about linguistics on English Language & Usage.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/456824/72143), which discusses [haplology](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplologie) (the disappearance of one or more repeated or close phonemes). Wikipedia gives some examples:

- **l'ectricité** for **l'électricité**
- **Oui, j'irai** for **Oui, j'y irai**
- **Oui, j'en ai obtenu** for **Oui, j'en en ai obtenu**

I've only ever heard the second example in everyday use. There are better examples in English like the following:

- **probly** for **probably** (I use this all the time!)
- **bana** for **banana** (often used by children younger than 3)
- **libry** for **library** (I don't use it very much, but I hear it often)

**Are there better examples of haplology in everyday French?**

Comment: If someone said "l'ectricité" instead of "l'électricité" I would assume that they don't speak French correctly or that they are trying to emulate Homer Simpson's pronunciation of "bibliothèque".

Comment: @najibidrissi sauf erreu Homer le prononce "blibliothèque"

Comment: Je ne pense pas que "J'en en ai obtenu" soit correct. "J'en ai obtenu" est le résultat du remplacement du e de "Je" par une apostrophe

Comment: @LaurentS. *J'en en ai obtenu* ne se dit pas mais les deux « en » y ont un rôle différent. *As-tu obtenu des renseignement ? Oui, j'en ai obtenu*: « en » représente les renseignements. *Qu'as tu obtenu de lui ? J'en ai obtenu des renseignements*: « en » représente la personne en question. La combinaison de ces deux « en » ne se réalise pas en français, la fusion en un seul « en » est la règle.

Answer (score 5):

L'**haplologie** est un phénomène linguistique courant. On  fait "sauter" (amuïssement) une des deux syllabes identiques qui se jouxtent dans un mot ou une phrase. Dans l'**hypoxépie**, c'est un simple phonème qui disparait. Des noms sont entrés dans l'usage sans qu'on s'en souvienne : *Clermont-Montferrand* est devenu Clermont-Ferrand et *tragico-comique* est devenu tragi-comique. On peut aussi citer  *contrôle* (issu de contre-rôle), *minéralogie* (de minéralo-logie) ou *féminisme* (de fémini-nisme).
Le phénomène n'est effectivement pas spécialement français : déjà, en gaulois, le dieu Toutatis est l’haplologie de touto-tatis, « père de la tribu » !

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly used as a joke or as slang but you might hear ***cahuète*** (or caouette) for ***cacahuète*** (*arachide*, peanut).

Comment: Que’est-ce que *cahuète* signifie en tant qu’argot ? Je ne l’ai jamais entendu.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Un peu comme *peanuts* en anglais, *cahuète* peut signifier *presque rien* ou *rien*.

Comment: Ah trop cool merci !

Comment: Mot popularisé par Serge Gainsbourg dans sa chanson « L'Ami Caouette »…

Answer (score 0):

You can also hear *cardentité* for *carte d'identité*, but in written, that would be used also rather for humour.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a les classiques **p'pa** et **m'man**, mais la "pause" est souvent un peu marqué, donc je sais pas si ça compte comme une Haplogie. (marrant que "Haplologie" soit "Haplologiable" ^^)

Je crois pas mal l'expression **t'taleur**, pour **tout à l'heure**, c'est le même "problème" que pour papa et maman, on entend la pause. (Et les syllabes sont proches mais différentes).

Comment: Ce serait plutôt à classer dans les aphérèses (amuïssement d'une syllabe en tête d'un mot ou d'une locution) comme dans bot (robot), Ricain (Américain) et tant d'autres.

Comment: Je pense effective que les consonnes initiales sont tenues un peu plus longtemps. De sorte que "t'taleur" se distingue de "t'as heure", /t:alœr/ ≠ /talœr/